# How to add to subtract prices using Javascript when user check/unchecks boxes?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of checkboxes with different prices for all items. How do I implement functionality If user select more than one item how do I add price to total or delete if unselect? In javascript.

I am new to javascript so pardon me if my code is not right.

```js
let pricesList = new Array();
pricesList["all"] = 200;
pricesList["js-frameworks"] = 100;
pricesList["js-libs"] = 100;
pricesList["express"] = 100;
pricesList["node"] = 100;
pricesList["build-tools"] = 100;
pricesList["npm"] = 100;
const activityCheckBoxes =    document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
function getActivityPrices(userInput) {
  // selected all checkBoxes
    
  // Loop through checkbox list
  for (let i = 0; i < activityCheckBoxes.length; i++) {
 if (activityCheckBoxes[i].checked) {
      userInput = activityCheckBoxes[i].name;
    }
  }
  return pricesList[userInput];
}
    
function calculateTotal() {
  let total = getActivityPrices();
  console.log(total);
  printIt.innerHTML = `Your Total is $${total}`;
  printIt.style.display = "block";
}
    
activities.onchange = calculateTotal;
```

```html
<fieldset class="activities">
 <legend>Register for Activities</legend>
 <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="all"> Main Conference — $200
 </label>
 <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="js-frameworks"> JavaScript Frameworks Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100
 </label>
 <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="js-libs"> JavaScript Libraries Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100
 </label>
 <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="express"> Express Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100
 </label>
 <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="node"> Node.js Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100
 </label>
 <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="build-tools"> Build tools Workshop — Wednesday 9am-12pm, $100
 </label>
 <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="npm"> npm Workshop — Wednesday 1pm-4pm, $100
 </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: add an event listener onto the checkboxes that runs `calculateTotal` on click

Comment: I tried that too what I am trying to achieve is real-time calculation so if the user selects/unselect total price changes. `checkBoxes[1].addEventListener("click", e => {
      disableBoxes(checkBoxes[1], checkBoxes[5], checkBoxes[3]);
      calculateTotal();
    });`

Comment: does this have to be pure javascript? can you do this in HTML and Javascript? can you use JQuery?

Comment: Yes pure javascript Its actually a project I am building for tech degree certification

Comment: Could you show your html please ?

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher I just added it to the code block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had quite a few errors - please take a look here at a revised version. Your pricesList should be an object, not an array!

```js
let pricesList = {};

pricesList["all"] = 200;
pricesList["js-frameworks"] = 100;
pricesList["js-libs"] = 100;
pricesList["express"] = 100;
pricesList["node"] = 100;
pricesList["build-tools"] = 100;
pricesList["npm"] = 100;

const main = document.getElementById('main');
const printIt = document.getElementById('printIt');

for (item in pricesList) {
  let box = '<div><input type="checkbox" id='+item+' name="'+pricesList[item]+'"/>'+
  '<label for="'+item+'">'+item+'  - price: $'+pricesList[item]+'</label></div>'
  main.innerHTML = main.innerHTML + box;
}

const activityCheckBoxes =     document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

function getActivityPrices(userInput) {
  // selected all checkBoxes
  let total = 0;
  // Loop through checkbox list
  for (let i = 0; i < activityCheckBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (activityCheckBoxes[i].checked) {
      userInput = parseInt(activityCheckBoxes[i].name);
      total = (total+userInput);
    }
  }
  return total
}

function calculateTotal() {
  let total = getActivityPrices();
  console.log(total);
  printIt.innerHTML = `Your Total is $${total}`;
  printIt.style.display = "block";
}

for (var i = 0; i < activityCheckBoxes.length; i++) {
  activityCheckBoxes[i].addEventListener('change',function(){
      calculateTotal();
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-family:arial;
}
#printIt {
margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>

<div id="printIt"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I see your code is doing what I want but when I tried to implement my total shows  **Your Total is $NaN**

Comment: when you say "tried to implement" what do you mean? where did you test this, what browser?

Comment: Code pen here's the link  [CodePen](https://codepen.io/iharmanpannu/pen/YeYwbq?editors=1010)

Comment: Looking at your codepen, I see the $ values fine using Chrome

Comment: Try one more time please I didn’t work for me in chrome either

Comment: Check this codepen please it works [link](https://codepen.io/iharmanpannu/pen/YeYwbq?editors=1010) and this image [link](https://imgur.com/VrcKykx)

Comment: you changed the code, your HTML uses strings for 'name' - that should be the value of your $$, as in the code I created. Let me adjust the codepen and repost for you ok?

Comment: i did not use correct values! just quickly replaced your strings with numbers. Add the names to your dataList object and created the checkboxes programatically, that would be cleaner!

Comment: please remember to give an upvote to any answers that have helped you

Comment: @StaceyReiman, why did you mention that it has to be an object instead of an array?

Comment: because Arrays in Javascript use the push() method to add elements, you were adding elements using pricesList['element'] - which is how you add elements to an Object, not an Array. An object is much better here, as you can add your checkbox names to the object key, along with the price. For example pricesList['all'] = {name: 'Main Conference', price: 200} - and so on. Then you can add your checkboxes programmatically, adding the names as well as the the prices to each checkbox with 1 simple loop. Much less code to write, and more extensible than hard coding your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

A dynamic approach, change to suit.

**Javascript**

```
var availableItems = getAvailableItems(),
    ledger = getLedger(),
    total = getTotal();

getStore().map(function(item) {
    var li = document.createElement('li'),
        checkbox = document.createElement('input'),
        label = document.createElement('label'),
        ledgerItem = document.createElement('li'),
        _item = item;

    ledgerItem.textContent = item.name+' costs $'+item.price;
    ledgerItem.classList.add(item.name.replace(/[^a-z\d-_]/gi, ''));

    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            ledgerItem.rel = item;
            ledger.appendChild(ledgerItem);
        } else {
            ledger.removeChild(ledgerItem);
        }
    });
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', setTotal);

    label.appendChild(checkbox);
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '+item.name));
    li.appendChild(label);
    availableItems.appendChild(li);
});

function setTotal() {
    var total = 0;

    Array.from(getLedgerItems()).forEach(item => total += item.rel.price);
    getTotal().value = '$'+total.toFixed(2);
}

function getStore() {
    return [
        {name: 'dog', price: 200.00},
        {name: 'cat', price: 100.00},
        {name: 'elephant', price: 5000.00},
        {name: 'bird', price: 0.99},
        {name: 'shark', price: 2500.00},
        {name: 'prairie dog', price: 5.00},
    ];
}

function getAvailableItems() {
    return document.getElementById('available-items');
}

function getAvailableItemsList() {
    return getAvailableItems().querySelectorAll('li');
}

function getLedger() {
    return document.getElementById('ledger');
}

function getLedgerItems() {
    return getLedger().querySelectorAll('li');
}

function getTotal() {
    return document.getElementById('total');
}
```

**CSS**

```
#total {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>Purchase</h1>
<p>Select Item(s):</p>
<ul id='available-items'></ul>
<h2>Ledger</h2>
<ul id='ledger'></ul>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Total:</th>
    <td><input disabled id='total' value='0.00'/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ameg8z6t/9

Answer (score 1):

https://jsbin.com/ruzelujoyu/edit?html,js,console,output

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="printIt"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="200" onchange="calculateTotal()"> All
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="100" onchange="calculateTotal()"> js-frameworks
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="100" onchange="calculateTotal()"> js-libs
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="100" onchange="calculateTotal()"> express
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="100" onchange="calculateTotal()"> node
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="100" onchange="calculateTotal()"> build-tools
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="100" onchange="calculateTotal()"> npm
  <br>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var pricesList = [];
pricesList["all"] = 200;
pricesList["js-frameworks"] = 100;
pricesList["js-libs"] = 100;
pricesList["express"] = 100;
pricesList["node"] = 100;
pricesList["build-tools"] = 100;
pricesList["npm"] = 100;

var activityCheckBoxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

function getActivityPrices() {
  var price = parseInt(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < activityCheckBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (activityCheckBoxes[i].checked) {
      price += parseInt(activityCheckBoxes[i].value);
    }
  }
  return price;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  var total = getActivityPrices();
  var printIt = document.getElementById("printIt");
  console.log(total);
  printIt.innerHTML = 'Your Total is $' + total;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified example describes how to solve the problem.
Press `Run code snippet` to test it

```js
function calculate() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  let result = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
      result += Number(inputs[i].value);
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = `Total : ${result}`;
}
```

```html
<h1>Total : 0</h1>
<input type="checkbox" name="js-framework" value="100" onChange="calculate()"> Js Framework<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="js-libs" value="100" onChange="calculate()"> JS Libs<br>
```